# Locked out of Ubuntu One account

Tags: login

I forgot my ubuntu one password and I asked for password reset but it keeps saying there are too many emails(even though there are none) so I should check my inbox. Once an email came through but it just took me back to the beginning to start the process again. What should I do or is there a technical support phone number?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a question about Ubuntu commercial support.

Comment: And you of course checked the spam folder?

Comment: It is not just for paid accounts, but everything related to Official Ubuntu sites such as Launchpad, wiki.ubuntu.com, and Software Center. Also other sites may use it.  I under you can even use it for AskUbuntu even though not an official Ubuntu site. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSO